# A series of externally tangent circles tangent to a line

Tags: circles

[image: Diagram & Question Statement]

I've been working on this question for a math class for awhile now and I don't really know where to go with it. I'm aware of the Kissing Circles Theorem, but in order to use it I have to prove it and I don't know how to go about doing that. I've tried connecting the centers of the circles and then dropping perpendiculars.

Comment: Please refer to another answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1877744/three-circles-touch-what-is-the-radius-of-smallest-circle).

Comment: That question isn't the same question as mine.

Comment: It's a more general case, substitute $a=b=1$, you can find $c$.  Repeat with the same manner with $r_i$, $r_{i+1}$ to get $r_{i+2}$.  It provides a hint for you and I didn't mark your question as duplicate.  Feel free to see the working.